# OpenMPI and Ubuntu 22.04 support for using all E and P cores on 12th gen Intel CPU?

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, cpu, intel, openmpi

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop with Intel 12th Gen CPU, with 8 p-cores and 8 e-cores. The CPU supports 24 total threads, 2 for each p-core and 1 for each e-core. Ubuntu identifies the model of the CPU correctly but only recognizes 12 cores and 24 threads. I am running parallel jobs with OpenMPI, which also complains if I try to use more than 12 cores. I also noticed some processes run much faster than others, likely due to the p-core vs e-core speed difference.

I am wondering if there are any suggestions to have Ubuntu and OpenMPI recognize all cores and hopefully distinguish p-cores vs e-cores?

Update:

Here is the output for `mpirun --display-map -n 1 true`:

`Data for JOB [3978,1] offset 0 Total slots allocated 12                                                                                                                                                                                         ========================   JOB MAP   ========================                                                                                                                                                                                   Data for node: xxxxxxxx Num slots: 12   Max slots: 0    Num procs: 1                                                    Process OMPI jobid: [3978,1] App: 0 Process rank: 0 Bound: socket 0[core 0[hwt 0-1]]:[BB/../../../../../../../../../../..]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       =============================================================`

and here is the output for `lscpu`:

> Architecture:            x86_64
> CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
> Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
> Byte Order:            Little Endian
> CPU(s):                  24
> On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
> Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
> Model name:            12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12800HX
> CPU family:          6
> Model:               151
> Thread(s) per core:  2
> Core(s) per socket:  12
> Socket(s):           1
> Stepping:            2
> BogoMIPS:            4608.01
> Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr
> pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse ss
> e2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl
> xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop                         _tsc cpuid pni
> pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt
> tsc_deadline                         _timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand
> hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single ssbd ibrs
> ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase
> tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi                         2 erms invpcid
> rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves
> avx_vnni u                         mip waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq
> rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm serialize flush_l1d arch_capabili
> ties
> Virtualization features:
> Virtualization:        VT-x
> Hypervisor vendor:     Microsoft
> Virtualization type:   full
> Caches (sum of all):
> L1d:                   576 KiB (12 instances)
> L1i:                   384 KiB (12 instances)
> L2:                    15 MiB (12 instances)
> L3:                    25 MiB (1 instance)
> Vulnerabilities:
> Itlb multihit:         Not affected
> L1tf:                  Not affected
> Mds:                   Not affected
> Meltdown:              Not affected
> Mmio stale data:       Not affected
> Retbleed:              Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS
> Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled
> via prctl and seccomp                              Spectre v1:
> Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
> Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional,
> RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence                Srbds:
> Not affected
> Tsx async abort:       Not affected

Comment: The default for Open MPI is to do 1 core = 1 slot. So if you really want 1 hwthread = 1slot, you have to `mpirun --use-hwthreads-as-cpus`. That being said, you generally do not want to use hwthreads since most apps do not benefit from them, and you might want to use only the P cores. Based on your description, I am afraid Open MPI only sees 12 (8+4) cores and this is something that could/should/will be improved. In order to confirm this, would you mind running `mpirun --display-map -n 1 true` and editing your question with the output?

Comment: I was wondering if I can use 8 p-cores and a couple of e-cores. I may end up using 12 as I am now but with more control to have the p-cores do more work. I am wondering if the 12 cores from OpenMPI or Ubuntu is just by 24/2. If so, it is interesting that it keeps the correct total threads instead of the total core number.

Comment: there is something fishy here: Open MPI seems to see 12 cores and 24 threads, but your description suggests it should be 16 cores and 24 threads (my previous comment was incorrect about 8+4).  can you please run `lscpu` and add the output to your question?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: E cores are great for algorithms that scale at all decently with more cores, and don't need all threads to run in lock-step.  They have pretty good throughput, much wider and beefier than early silvermont-family.  (Half the theoretical max FMA throughput of a P-core using 256-bit vectors, but 1/clock is pretty decent considering 4 E cores take about the same area as 1 P-core.)

Comment: I think you'd only want to consider avoiding them if your algorithm was unable to let a thread (or MPI worker) start a new block of work while others are still working, e.g. breaking the problem up into 1 piece per thread (not multiple smaller work units that could be scheduled dynamically according to which finished first).  With all pieces the same size, not adjusted to give E cores smaller pieces.   And/or if all workers need to finish their current work unit before any can start on the next (MPI_Barrier()), and you can't or haven't adjusted work distribution to give smaller to E cores.

Comment: @PeterCordes Agree "you generally do not want to use hwthreads since most apps do not benefit from them" was just an other way to say "most apps run in lock-step and/or are heavily synchronized"

Comment: Thanks, it seems `lscpu` is a bit confused with this cpu: 12 cores and 2 threads/per core is clearly not what is advertised at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/226058/intel-core-i712800hx-processor-25m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz/specifications.html?wapkw=i7-12800HX. Finally, and since `hwloc` might use a different method, could you please run and post `lstopo-no-graphics --version`, `lstopo-no-graphics --cpukinds` and  `lstopo-no-graphics --no-io --of xml`

Comment: FWIW, I filed https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/11345 in order to follow up on that

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: It's been a while since I did anything with MPI, but I guess people use it (instead of threads when targeting a single system) when an algorithm divides more neatly into lock-step workers, and you want those barrier primitives?  The usual HPC reasons to not run use both logical cores of each physical core are that they compete for cache footprint (L1d and L2), and well-optimized loops (e.g. in a matmul) can already saturate the execution resources and/or memory-level parallelism of a core.  But the E cores are throughput resources that would go entirely unutilized.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: In an application that doesn't account for different throughput ratios and has a lot of lock-step stuff, yeah it might be better to leave the E cores idle, but there is significant performance left on the table in that case which better algorithms could potentially use.  (So it could be a matter of development time and code complexity vs. performance, a common tradeoff that doesn't always go in favour of more performance).  Unlike with hyperthreading where there's not really anything more to be gained with well-tuned code on each core.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, most apps ends up running at the pace of the slowest cpu, that is why a heterogeneous system is generally not recommended. Also, the floating point units is generally shared by two threads from the the same core, so unless the app only computes integer, hyperthreading has generally little to no value performance wise.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: We're talking about whether to use the E-cores or not.  Each E core is a fully separate core with its own execution units, including for SIMD instructions.  Unlike with hyperthreading where two logical cores share the same physical core, where *all* execution resources (integer and FP) are competitively shared.  You're thinking of AMD Bulldozer-family, where two weak integer cores shared an FPU (so good integer performance wasn't available to single-threaded code), but neither Intel nor AMD have built CPUs that way for years.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: You're correct that hyperthreading has little to no performance value (or even negative from cache effects) for HPC or other well-tuned code that doesn't stall much.   But that's irrelevant to whether E-cores are useful.  The only reason to avoid them is with an algorithm that scales very poorly (sub-linear speedup with number of cores), or runs at the speed of the slowest core (and you're on a machine where the P cores provide more than half the total throughput, given thermal limits.  A laptop *might* sustain better throughput on E cores with the P cores asleep.)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: The shared-FPU between two integer cores design, AMD Bulldozer, is detailed in https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/.  Modern Intel CPUs are still Sandybridge-family, at least the big core (P-cores) https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/.   Intel introduced SMT into i7-series CPUs with Nehalem, https://www.realworldtech.com/nehalem/3/ . (SMT is the generic name for the thing Intel brands Hyperthreading.) Re: P-cores vs. E-cores in Alder Lake, [What are performance and efficiency cores in Intel's 12th Generation Alder lake CPU Line?](https://superuser.com/a/1677779)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: In case it wasn't clear, I'm suggesting that to use all the throughput of the machine, you'd want one thread per P core and one thread per E core.  So 16 threads on the OP's 16c24t CPU, for a problem that isn't slowed down by E cores.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue I am having is that OpenMPI only sees 12 cores. I have to add --use-hwthreads-as-cpus to get it to accept more than 12. But I am not sure if it put two threads on a single core, the worse case being the e-core. At this point I have no idea how the OpenMPI handles the scheduling.

Comment: the 12 slots thing is definitely fishy as there are indeed 16. Please post the output of `lstopo-no-graphics --no-io --of xml` so I can rule whether the hardware is not correctly detected by `hwloc`, or Open MPI misinterpret it.